# How to test route's willTransition action in Ember?

Tags: ember.js, qunit, ember-testing

How can I test this code in Ember? Explain me please the concept, in general.

```
// app/routes/products/new.js
import Ember from 'ember';

export default Ember.Route.extend({
  model() {
    return this.store.createRecord('product');
  },
  actions: {
    willTransition() {
      this._super(...arguments);
      this.get('controller.model').rollbackAttributes();
    }
  }
});
```

I have no idea how to make this. May be stub model in route? I found that store is not available in route test.

After Ruby and RSpec, all these new javascript world is confusing a little bit) But I'd like to learn it anyway.

Comment: Cour code is wrong ;), `willTransition` is an hook, not an action. Don't put it in the `actions` hash. And you could just call it to rest it. You can stub the store.

Comment: @Lux to write our logic in `willTransition` hook we should define it in actions right ?.

Comment: @Lux, Hmm, you know, according to the guide https://guides.emberjs.com/v2.8.0/routing/preventing-and-retrying-transitions/ willTransition appears in actions hash. "When a transition is attempted, whether via {{link-to}}, transitionTo, or a URL change, a willTransition action is fired on the currently active routes." - they call it "action", not "hook".

Comment: Unrelated, but currentModel is a private method, and is not the"ember" way of grabbing your.....current model.... in the route: https://github.com/emberjs/ember.js/issues/11760

I'm not very knowledgeable about testing in Ember yet, but if you cannot access the store from the test, I am not sure you can test this. Rollback attributes, in the given example, will delete the unsaved model from the store, or remove any unsaved changes from an existing model - again from the store.

Comment: okay, obviously I was wrong. sorry. Thats interesting.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In unit tests the idea is to stub all external dependencies. In ember you can do this:

```
// tests/unit/products/new/route-test.js
test('it should rollback changes on transition', function(assert) {
  assert.expect(1);
  let route = this.subject({
    controller: Ember.Object.create({
      model: Ember.Object.create({
        rollbackAttributes() {
          assert.ok(true, 'should call rollbackAttributes on a model');
        }
      })
    })
  });
  route.actions.willTransition.call(route);
});
```

Basically you stub controller and model passing them to `this.subject()`, then call whatever function you are testing (in this case you have to use call or apply to call an action with the correct scope), and then assert that `rollbackAttributes()` was called.

`assert.expect(1);` at the start of a test tells QUnit to wait for exactly 1 assertion.

Comment: Just a minor note, instead of using `route.actions.willTransition.call(route);
` you could call `route.send('willTransition');`